# Windows Forms C++

Tags: windows, winforms

I have just started to learn C++, and I would like to learn how to make Windows Forms C++ applications.

Could anyone recommend some good ebooks?

I have a small converter program that I have made. It runs from the console, but I would like to make a nice GUI for it.

The form is quickly made in Visual Studio, but then I need to insert some code. This is were I got stuck.

I haven't been able to find any tutorial. Well found some, but they used C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Just a hint: C++ in your case is also not pure C++ but has to be C++/CLR to work with the .NET Winforms. C# in this case is the most natural language and would make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jdehaan said, [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) is a .NET component and is not pure C++, it is definitely different. If you need to decide which to use, the book [Beginning Visual C++ 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470225904)  was helpful for me, as it teaches C++/CLI and regular Windows C++ forms. I'm not sure how hard this would be to find online.

If you are serious about Windows Forms programming and do not need easy interoperability between native and managed code, I would definitely suggest you just go with learning C#. Visual C++ feels Frankenstein-ish to me, and support is definitely waning in the editor. The managed versions of the languages are so similar that if you are going to learn .NET, C# would be the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answers (jdehaan and Nathan)
I'll try to find the book you linked to.